# Mysql self join gives weird results

Tags: mysql, self-join

I have this table with:

```
 id|subject          | parent_id
 1 |ladbore          | 2
 2 |quod             | NULL
 3 |cumque           | 6
 4 |ut               | 3
 5 |sed              | NULL
 6 |reprehenderit    | 1
 7 |qui              | 4
 8 |eum              | 6
 9 |deserunt         | 6
10 |et               | 6
```

Now I have created a self-join to get all subjects including the name of the subject of the parent like so:

```
SELECT 
 `subject`. `id`,
 `subject`.`subject` AS `subject_name`,
 `parent`.`subject` AS `parent_name`
FROM
`subjects` AS `subject`
LEFT JOIN
`subjects` AS  `parent`  
ON  
`parent`.`id` = `subject`.`id`;
```

However this gives me the following weird result:

```
id  subject_name    parent_name
1   labore          labore
2   quod            quod
3   cumque          cumque
4   ut              ut
5   sed             sed
6   reprehenderit   reprehenderit
7   qui             qui
8   eum             eum
9   eserunt         deserunt
10  et              et
```

Why does this give the wrong result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just joining records against themselves, since you've got `parent.id = subject.id`. If you want a tree structure in your table, then you need `(id, parent_id, ...)` as the fields, and join on `subject.parent_id = parent.id`

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be

```
SELECT 
 `subject`. `id`,
 `subject`.`subject` AS `subject_name`,
 `parent`.`subject` AS `parent_name`
FROM
`subjects` AS `subject`
LEFT JOIN
`subjects` AS  `parent`  
ON  
`parent`.`id` = `subject`.`parent_id`;
```